# How to place a image using imageview below tabbed bar in android?

Tags: android, imageview, android-constraintlayout

I am using constraint layout. When i place a image in the image view it directly aligns to the center of the screen vertically with huge space between the tab bar and the image. I cant bring it exactly below the tab bar.The image resolution is 2048*1152. Im planning on using it as a banner for my app. This is the code:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context="com.manu.program.MainTwo">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/banner_image"
    />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

When i run the app i get the result as shown in the attached image [need to remove the space between the image and tab bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbQi8.jpg)

Comment: add adjustViewBounds=true in image view

Comment: put your full xml

Comment: set imageview height wrap_content

Comment: give android:scaleType="fitXY" for ImageView

Comment: Why do you have to use `ConstraintLayout` anyway? `RelativeLayout` or `LinearLayout` should be applicable here.

Comment: I used both adjustViewBounds=true and  height wrap_content. It worked. android:scaleType="fitXY" also worked. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To place your image below tab, you can use "android:scaleType="fitStart". It will take your image into top,
without effecting any aspect ratio.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
    android:id="@+id/section_label"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:scaleType="fitStart"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/flower" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```